# Correct concurrency approach to swing animation?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation, concurrency

I am about to write an animation in which a character on a `JPanel` moves left/right when the user presses (and holds) the appropriate keys.

Now, since I am new to *concurrency* I want to ask : should the code handling the animation (namely the method that will move and repaint the character as long as the key is held) be executed on a worker thread or the event dispatch thread ?

I read the tutorials on concurrency in `swing`, and it seems that stuff that changes the components (in this case it's painting `JPanel`) should be on the event handling thread, but on the other hand that would freeze all the other events as long as a key would be held right ?

For example a user won't be able to pause the game while he's holding the go-left key, if I understand this correctly. So which approach is correct and why? Or maybe there is totally different way to make such an animation ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you are going to draw implicitly, a simple thread approach would help, because there is no any conflicts between underlying thread and your thread, like [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#lc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Drawings Paintings need to be done on EDT thread. Never on any other Thread . Use 
SwingUtilities.invokeLater()  .. for  your painting. You can do calculations like what will be the next postion of your character on Worker Thread. You won't have any unresponsiveness if you are doing creating and using Swing Classes on EDT. just Make sure that your computation is not too long. For Animation whenever you find the next positon of your Character just call 
SwingUtilties.invokeLater to update changes on UI

Comment: Well, thank you for clearing that up then. Just one more thing to be sure: by "my computation" you mean only the code calculating where will the character be in the next frame right?